# El Capitan: CRON Job is unable to trigger a shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell, cron, sh

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /dataScience/dat/JOB/forker.sh
```

Above is the cron job which does not execute. I have checked separately both the functioning of cron job and shell script which works fine. Even the below command works well.

```
/bin/sh /dataScience/dat/JOB/forker.sh
```

I have also checked the permissions of `forker.sh` which shows

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 mango  wheel   442 Nov 20 12:53 forker.sh
```

Am i missing something which restricts the cron job from triggering the script?

Comment: How do you know the cron job does not execute? Did a subcommand within the script not run? Check value of `PATH` variable inside the script when run via `cron`. Also make sure that you want to run it with `sh` and not `bash`. There should not be any `bash` specific code (A.K.A. bashism) in the script you are running with `sh`... Also, given that `/dataScience` is a non-standard path, does it require any NFS/disk mounting?

Comment: forker.sh outputs the content to a file. However, if you think the command / logic has failed. the first line of command inserts current date into the log file which i don't see either. To be sure I wanted to use `sh` i have used `/bin/sh` and calling the script file.

Comment: How do I identify bash specific code? `/dataScience` is a folder created on the primary disk and does not require any specific mounting.

Comment: Some (read: many) syntaxes are added in bash, which were not part of traditional bourne shell (sh). You can check by pasting your script at http://shellcheck.net along with a `#!/bin/sh` line at start... Alternately, there are editor plugins of [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) project, which can work same as the online tool.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the syntax for the job goes like:

> minute hour dom month dow user cmd

In your case, the job might be for multiple user, it seems

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/sh /dataScience/dat/JOB/forker.sh
```

Which implies it should be run at the interval of 10 mins all the time. Which is not problematic.

Can you tell us if the following is giving you the output at all?

```
*/10 * * * * (echo "Printing."; echo "Logging." > /dataScience/dat/JOB/abc.txt | mail -s "Mailing" your_email)
```

**Note: I wanted to comment this, since this is not exactly the answer but debugging, but I have reputation lesser than 50, hence couldn't comment.**

Comment: The command succeeded but i see only `Logging`in the `abc.txt` file. mangos-Mac:JOB mango$ ls
abc.txt  genD  genD_BKP
forker.sh genD.log tst.sh
mangos-Mac:JOB mango$ cat abc.txt 
Logging.

Comment: It doesn't seem an issue with cron but something with the permissions because other daemons run using cron. 
Any other help in this regard?